# atomic structure - why only hydrogen be separately written in periodic table

Tags: hydrogen, periodic-table, atomic-structure

> The other
> exception is hydrogen. It has only one
> s-electron and hence can be placed in group 1
> (alkali metals). It can also gain an electron to
> achieve a noble gas arrangement and hence it
> can behave similar to a group 17 (halogen
> family) elements. Because it is a special case,
> we shall place hydrogen separately at the top
> of the Periodic Table

lithium can also loose one electron and behave like a noble element so should we also place all ns1 and ns2 element separately at top ?

Comment: You neglected question preparation. How many electrons does H atom need to gain electron configuration of the next noble gas? And Li atom?

Comment: While most alkali metals do form anions, these do not have a noble gas configuration. Only hydride ion from this group does. Also hydride ions exist in a radically different environment from natride and heavier congeners.

Comment: In short, H and He are the two having 1s electrons configuration. It is quite natural to place them in the same period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not the complete explanation why Hydrogen is placed separately. Hydrogen is highly electropositive like alkali metals and forms bonds with halogens. It also has high ionization enthalpy like halogens while alkali metals easily loose electrons. Similarly various other factors contribute special placement of hydrogen and not just it's electronic configuration.